# Javascript client/server module conventions

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, commonjs

Are there conventions for writing a Javascript middle-ware library that would be used on both the client and the server?

Say we have a data abstraction layer, let's call it [JEFRi](http://jefri.org). The JEFRi runtime needs to run the same in both the client and the server, so that all parts of the application using the DAL can reference the same implementation, API, etc. JEFRi has dependencies (specifically underscore), and has submodules that depend on it (Mongo storage, LocalStore storage).

What is the most direct pattern that can be used to allow easiest code sharing between the browser and node?

It should:

- be installable on the server using NPM
- be loadable in the server using CommonJS `require()` calls
- be installable for a browser project using one of: ender, bower, npm
- be installable for a browser project by copying a .min.js that does not have library dependencies within the file.
- be loadable on a page using `<script>` tags (and registering itself in the global scope)
- be loadable on a page using AMD `define()` and `require()` calls

Any number of build steps are acceptable, eg to call r.js if necessary.

Comment: Yes, I am aware my previous question on this topic was closed as "Non Constructive". Would whomever is closing it as such mind leaving a comment as to why they find it non constructive? This is a non-trivial problem in the Javascript development world, that I've not seen discussed in blogs. Having an answer for what should be a common use case would be a Good Thing.